# Hide Multiple Excel Worksheets

Tags: linux, excel, perl

I am using the Perl module [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://p3rl.org/Excel::Writer::XLSX) to write an Excel workbook in Linux. I am writing to three separate worksheets and am trying to hide the first two so that only the third worksheet is visible.

**Perl Code:**

```
$worksheet3->activate();
$worksheet1->hide();
$worksheet2->hide();
```

Instead, using the code below, only the first worksheet tab is being hidden.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the order of the tabs related to when the worksheets are created? Can you provide a full [mcve] that includes creating a file and adding sheets please?

Comment: And if you activate the third a second time after hiding the first??

Comment: No need `$worksheet3->activate()` since the two sheet hidden then there is no option instead the third one.

Comment: Yes. This is the issue don't use `$worksheet3->activate()`.

Comment: Right @toolic. My thinking was setting the third worksheet as the default before hiding the first two but, apparently that won't work. Pretty stuck at the moment.

Comment: Also, I have the latest version of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Sheet2 won't be visible until it is unhidden in Excel.
$worksheet1->hide();
$worksheet2->hide();
```

> Please activate the excel after the hidden sheets.

```
$worksheet3->activate();
```

I have tested this.

Comment: So you're saying move the `activate` to the bottom?

Comment: Obliviously and the same has been tested.

Comment: This worked perfectly and I have marked it as my answer. Thanks for all of the help @ssr1012!